# Apache Spark Python Cosine Similarity over DataFrames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cosine-similarity

For a Recommender System, I need to compute the cosine similarity between all the columns of a whole Spark DataFrame.

In Pandas I used to do this:

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame(...some dataframe over here :D ...)
metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(df.T,df.T)
```

That generates the Similarity Matrix between the columns (since I used the transposition)

Is there any way to do the same thing in Spark (Python)?

(I need to apply this to a matrix made of tens of millions of rows, and thousands of columns, so that's why I need to do it in Spark)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the built-in `columnSimilarities()` method on a `RowMatrix`, that can both calculate the exact cosine similarities, or estimate it using the [DIMSUM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1467) method, which will be considerably faster for larger datasets. The difference in usage is that for the latter, you'll have to specify a `threshold`.

Here's a small reproducible example:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
rows = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)])

# Convert to RowMatrix
mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# Calculate exact and approximate similarities
exact = mat.columnSimilarities()
approx = mat.columnSimilarities(0.05)

# Output
exact.entries.collect()
[MatrixEntry(0, 2, 0.991935352214),
 MatrixEntry(1, 2, 0.998441152599),
 MatrixEntry(0, 1, 0.997463284056)]
```

Comment: How can I do over the rows instead of the columns?

Comment: @mtoto Do you know how to implement the same in Scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010126/calculate-cosine-similarity-spark-dataframe

Comment: Can you interpret the results of the matrixEntry? like what is 0 and 2?

Comment: First 2 elements of MatrixEntry correspond to row index and column index. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/MatrixEntry.html

Comment: @Charleslmh in order to do it over rows, you need to get a transpose of the RowMatrix.