# How to compute cosine similarity between two words in Word2Vec model in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, word2vec, gensim

When I use the python library `gensim` and train a Word2Vec model, I can call the function like this `word2vec_result.similarity('apple','banana')` to get the cosine similarity between apple and banana at local machine. 
But in `pyspark(version2.2)`, I can't find the same function in the document after the model built.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2VecModel
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import logging
directory = "data_path"  
inp = sc.textFile(directory).map(lambda row: row.split(" "))
model = word2vec_run(inp)
model.save(sc, "/data/word2vec_model")
```

Are there any simple ways to achieve the goal?

Comment: I think there is no such function. If you want the similarity value to get the similar words, you can use findSynonyms() method. otherwise ,believe we need to use workaround,check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921636/apache-spark-python-cosine-similarity-over-dataframes

Comment: @Suresh , thank you very much for reply. I thank i have to find other way to solve this problem.