# Pairwise similarity calculation in PySpark RDD takes forever

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, cosine-similarity

I have an RDD (called "data") where each row is an id/vector pair, like so:

```py
 [('1',
   array([ 0.16501912, -0.25183533, -0.07702908,  0.07335572,  0.15868553])),
  ('2',
  array([ 0.01280832, -0.27269777,  0.09148506,  0.03950897,  0.15832097])),
```

I need to calculate pair-wise similarity for this RDD, comparing each row with every other row.  I tried this:

```py
pairs  = data.cartesian(data)\
        .map(lambda l: ((l[0][0], l[1][0]), l[1][1].dot(l[1][1])))\
        .sortByKey()
```

But this is taking forever, as the RDD is about 500k rows.  I wonder if there's a better way?  I am using pyspark.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Convert to dataframe, write a udf.

Comment: It is 25e10 operations - taking forever is expected, unless you have __a lot__ of resources, and even then transferring data alone will be very expensive.  The better way is not to __calculate pair-wise similarity__ and find approximation which works well in your case.

Comment: You can go for [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH)

Comment: Try to first cluster your data into similar groups, then run the cartesian product within those smaller groups

Comment: Take a look at this one and see if that helps? It helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663775/spark-cosine-distance-between-rows-using-dataframe