# Calculate the cosine distance between two column in Spark

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark

I am using a Python & Spark to solve an issue.
I have dataframe containing two columns in a Spark Dataframe
Each of the columns contain a scalar of numeric(e.g. double or float) type.

I want to interpret these two column as vector and calculate  consine similarity between them.
Sofar I only found spark linear algebra that can be used on densevector that are located in cell of the dataframe.

code sample

Code in numpy

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
vec = np.array([1, 2])
vec_2 = np.array([2, 1])
angle_vec_vec = (np.dot(vec, vec))/(norm(vec * norm(vec)))
print(angle_vec_vec )
```

Result should 0.8

How to do this in Spark ?

```
df_small = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (2, 1)])
df_small.show()
```

Is there a way to convert a column of double values to a densevector ?
Do you see any other soluation to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala) a sample that calculates the cosine distance in Scala. The strategy is to represent the documents as a RowMatrix and then use its columnSimilarities() method.

If you want to use PySpark, you can try what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663775/spark-cosine-distance-between-rows-using-dataframe)