# how can i compute similarity degree scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bioinformatics

I'm working on a similarity computing function on an RDD containing protein names and their domains.

Actually i used the cartisian function to determine all possible pairs in my rdd, they look like

```
((**P29535**,IPR004839;IPR004838;IPR015424;IPR015422;IPR0154),(**A6MML6**,IPR034733;IPR000438;IPR029045;IPR0117))
```

(PS: its just an example, the resulting pairs that i found are millions..)

the words written in bold are the proteins names and the rest is their domains.
can you please help me to determine the similarity degree between them based on their domains?

i would like to have a result such as:

```
*protein_name1* + "and" + *protein_name2* + "have a similiarity degree equals to:" + *similarity*
```

Comment: is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43922384/2129801) helpful?

Comment: @werner sorry i didn't see any answer.. where is it?

Comment: I meant the link in my comment. Maybe this link can give you a hint? If not, just ignore my comment

Comment: oh thank you but this is python not scala!